# Fixed elements with no locations declared inherit static positions?

Tags: css

I've noticed that an element with `position:fixed`, but no values declared for `top`, `bottom`, `left`, or `right`, gets positioned as though it were static, but does not scroll.

This is the case in every browser I've tested, and it's quite a useful thing to know, but I can't find any reference to this (after a brief search).

Basically, is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the horse's mouth...

> ...fixed boxes do not move when the document is scrolled.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning).

To me, that sums up the behaviour that you are seeing. No matter where you position it, it will not scroll with the viewport.

Comment: I know it wouldn't scroll, that's always explicitly stated about fixed elements. I'm asking whether I should have expected the element to inherit a static position (as opposed to just appearing in the upper-left corner or something)?

Comment: @Isaac Yes, that is what I said in the last paragraph.

Comment: Just making sure I was clear and also hearing you right. That is awesome, since I can set the fixed element's static container to `margin:0 auto` and now the fixed element is centered.

Comment: @Isaac It is handy, just remember it isn't supported in IE6 and is buggy in IE7.